# What is the difference between CKRM and cgroup.

Tags: resources, kernel

Are they same?

Could some one please explain in detail. I have gone through the web links and found both do the resource management.

Is one is newer than the other one?

How a multimedia application can utilize this in its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKRM (**C**lass-based **K**ernel **R**esource **M**anagement) project started to give better resource management in linux kernel and later its been stoped and not mearged with linux kernel.

Later similar project started for same purpose called cgroup and mearged with 2.6 onwards.

We can also get more details from linux source code Documentation's cgroup directory.

In my system its: /usr/src/linux-3.14.1/Documentation/cgroups